# Fast paletted screen blit with Direct3D 9

Tags: 2d, direct3d, palette

A game uses software rendering to draw a full-screen paletted (8-bit) image in memory.

What's the fastest way to put that image on the screen, using Direct3D?

Currently I convert the paletted image to RGB in software, then put it on a `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC` texture (which is locked with `D3DLOCK_DISCARD`).

Is there a faster way? E.g. using shaders to perform palettization?

Related questions:

- [Fast paletted screen blit with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524813/fast-paletted-screen-blit-with-opengl) - same question with OpenGL
- [How do I improve Direct3D streaming texture performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912404/how-do-i-improve-direct3d-streaming-texture-performance) - similar question from SDL author

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `D3DFMT_L8` texture containing the paletted image, and an 256x1 `D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8` image containing the palette.

HLSL shader code:

```
uniform sampler2D image;
uniform sampler1D palette;

float4 main(in float2 coord:TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    return tex1D(palette, tex2D(image, coord).r * (255./256) + (0.5/256));
}
```

Note that the luminance (palette index) is adjusted with a multiply-add operation. This is necessary, as palette index 255 is considered as white (maximum luminance), which becomes 1.0f when represented as a float. Reading the palette texture at that coordinate causes it to wrap around (as only the fractionary part is used) and read the first palette entry instead.

Compile it with:

```
fxc /Tps_2_0 PaletteShader.hlsl /FhPaletteShader.h
```

Use it like this:

```
// ... create and populate texture and paletteTexture objects ...
d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader((DWORD*)g_ps20_main, &shader)
// ...
d3dDevice->SetTexture(1, paletteTexture);
d3dDevice->SetPixelShader(shader);
// ... draw texture to screen as textured quad as usual ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple pixel shader to handle the palettization. Create an L8 dynamic texture and copy your paletteized image to it and create a palette lookup texture (or an array of colors in constant memory). Then just render a fullscreen quad with the palettized image set as a texture and a pixel shader that performs the palette lookup from the lookup texture or constant buffer.

That said, performing the palette conversion on the CPU shouldn't be very expensive on a modern CPU. Are you sure that is your performance bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. CPU usage increases dramatically in 32-bit DirectDraw vs. 8-bit paletted DirectDraw. I'm looking into shaders right now, thanks (trying to figure out how to bind the palette texture to the sampler uniform variable).

Comment: Since the palette is only 256 entries and you don't need to take advantage of texture blending or anything you could just use a constant buffer for your palette entries which would be a bit simpler on the shader / binding side than using a texture (assuming D3D11).

Comment: I just noticed that you're using D3D9, you should still be able to use constants for the palette lookup I think but there are restrictions on indexed constant look ups in pixel shaders in D3D9 as I remember so a palette texture is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, figured everything out (see my answer below).